# How to use the official docker image to be a service in GitLab CI?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

### Environment:

- GitLab Community Edition 9.5.2

---

### Description:

I used the `node:8.4.0` be my main image. It will do something Node.js program in the other jobs, and I will ignore them below.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: node:8.4.0

services:
  - docker:latest

stages:
  - docker_build

docker_build_job:
  stage: docker_build
  script:
    - sudo docker build -t my_name/repo_name .
    - sudo docker images
```

---

### Problem:

I cannot use the `docker` command in GitLab runner, and get the message below:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.0 (413da38)
  on ci server running on a VM of PEM5208 (5a0ceca0)
Using Docker executor with image node:8.4.0 ...
Starting service docker:latest ...
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Using docker image docker:latest ID=sha256:be47faef67c2e5950a540799e72189867b517010ad8ef98aa0181878d81b0064 for docker service...
Waiting for services to be up and running...

*** WARNING: Service runner-5a0ceca0-project-129-concurrent-0-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.

exit code 1

*********

Using docker image sha256:3f7a536cd71bb3049cc0aa12fb3e131a03a33efe2175ffbb95216d264500d1a1 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image node:8.4.0 ...
Using docker image node:8.4.0 ID=sha256:60bea5b8607945a43b53f5022088a73f2817174e11a3b20f78ea78a45f545d34 for build container...
Running on runner-5a0ceca0-project-129-concurrent-0 via ci...
Fetching changes...
Removing node_modules/
HEAD is now at 472e1e4 Change the version of docker image.
From https://here-is-my-domain/my_name/repo_name
   472e1e4..df29530  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 472e1e45 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts for build_installation_job (914)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=914 responseStatus=200 OK token=fMsaFRzG
$ docker build -t my_name/repo_name .
/bin/bash: line 48: docker: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How should I modify the YAML file of gitlab-ci, make it work successfully?

Comment: Try with `image: docker:dind` and remove `services:
  - docker:latest`. See if that helps

Comment: Dear. I got a new error message. `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: Ok try `image: docker:latest` and `services: - docker:dind`

Comment: Sorry, I got the error message like below.  `Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-5a0ceca0-project-129-concurrent-0-docker-0 AS /runner-5a0ceca0-project-129-concurrent-0-docker-0-wait-for-service/runner-5a0ceca0-project-129-concurrent-0-docker-0`

Comment: Which runner are you using? can you post the runner details also to the question

Comment: I'm not the admin of the system. Have any method can get the information for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153739/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-husky).

Comment: Dear @TarunLalwani and the others, I solved this question that followed this article. https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-shell-executor

Comment: Please post an answer yourself with the final yaml that you used and accept it as an answer. Instead of link post the correct yaml so that it helps others also

Comment: Dear. Copy that. I will do this soon. Thanks for your comment a lot.

Comment: @Husky can you post your working YAML?